# Setting border of containing div changes its size dramatically

Tags: html, css

Take this HTML.
If you take out that "border: 1px solid" from the yellow box, its size changes a lot (it shrinks considerably).

...why?

**UPDATE**: If I change the `p` as inline-block, the size stays the same. So, that `p` tag seems to be the problem... but why would a border in the outer div make an inline tag change its size so dramatically?

```
<body style="height:100%">

  <div style="background-color: red; border-style:solid;">
    <div style="background-color: yellow; border:1px solid;">
      <p>Inside</p>
    </div>
    <p>Something</p>
  </div>


  <div style="background-color: blue; border-style:solid;">
    <p>Something else </p>
  </div>

</body>
```

Demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/C2D49/

Comment: For reference/testing - http://jsfiddle.net/BbKED/

Comment: I don't know how it's related, but it has to do with `<p>`'s margins

Comment: The div is indeed increasing its size by exactly P's margin (which is 16 pixels).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go :-

[Margin Collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/margin_collapsing)

### Adjacent siblings

`The margins of adjacent siblings are collapsed (except when the later sibling needs to be cleared past floats). For example:
 <p>The bottom margin of this paragraph is collapsed...</p>
 <p>...with the top margin of this paragraph.<p>`

### Parent and first/last child

`If there is no border, padding, inline content, or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block with the margin-top of its first child block, or no border, padding, inline content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block with the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.`

### Empty blocks

`If there is no border, padding, inline content, height, or min-height to separate a block's margin-top from its margin-bottom, then its top and bottom margins collapse.`

Have a look at this fiddle- It doesnt collapse now after adding just a couple of spans.
http://jsfiddle.net/aPaBy/

```
<div style="background-color: red; border-style:solid;">
   <div id="test" class="border" style="background-color: yellow;">
     <span>hi</span>
      <p>Inside <button>Test</button></p>
     <span>hi</span>
    </div>
    <p>Something</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Oh my... I hit such a edge case, it's not even funny. But... why? I mean, seriously, why? It's not a very common case, but still...

Answer (score 0):

I think it is due to the reason that you are not doing any resets in it... try this one...
in your CSS add

```
*{margin:0px;padding:0px;}
```

now give the margin and padding as much as you want... it will work as charm... give it a shot

I've edited your fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/BbKED/1/